# onclick pagination link, session expired in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

IN Controller,

```
    public function index($offset = 0)
    {   
        $state= $this->input->post('state');
        $city= $this->input->post('city');
        $data = array(
                'state' => $state,
                'cities' => $city
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $data['active']='Search';

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url']= site_url()."search/index/";
        $config['total_rows']= 100;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 4;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $result = $this->mymodel->search($city,$state,$offset);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['search_result']=$this->build_result_html();
        $this->load->view('search',$data);
    }
```

In view Pagination displaying properly but,
on click of pagination link then session always expired
please help me
Thanks.

Comment: did you create flash_session or only session

Comment: @MohitJain above is the exact code of my controller, my problem is on click of pagination button session expiring. please help me

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: @MohitJain, no any error if i var_dump($data) then first time it's coming data, but on click of pagination link then var_dump($data) return empty data.

Comment: try to print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); check did you get your value

Comment: @MohitJain first time it's coming like,  `Array ( [session_id] => 1469158fd0ba028dcaf9b3e9bf3facde [ip_address] => ::1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0 [last_activity] => 1396074927 [user_data] => [state] => Andhra Pradesh [cities] => Hyderabad )` and onclick of pagination link it's coming like `Array ( [session_id] => 1469158fd0ba028dcaf9b3e9bf3facde [ip_address] => ::1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0 [last_activity] => 1396074927 [user_data] => [state] => [cities] => ) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use get instead of post to fetch data. I tat way iu dont need to create a session for it.

Your controller becomes some thing like this.

```
public function index($offset = 0)
    {   
        $state= $this->input->get('state');
        $city= $this->input->get('city');

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url']= site_url()."search/index/";
        $config['total_rows']= 100;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 4;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $result = $this->mymodel->search($city,$state,$offset);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['search_result']=$this->build_result_html();
        $this->load->view('search',$data);
    }
```

I your search for u need to add a attribute to form `method="get"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $state= $this->input->post('state');
  $city= $this->input->post('city');
if(!empty($city) && !empty($state) ){
        $this->session->set_userdata('state',$state);
         $this->session->set_userdata('cities',$city);
    }
```

i try on my local

```
$state= 'asdasd';
     $city= 'asdasd';
    if(!empty($city) && !empty($state) ){   // if its having value then set session
            $this->session->set_userdata('state',$state);
             $this->session->set_userdata('cities',$city);
        }
        print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

output is

```
Array ( [session_id] => 2c717eb44e99fb1def09af56250aa5bc [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36 [last_activity] => 1396079813 [user_data] => [id] => 2 [name] => [state] => sadfasd [cities] => fddsfdf )
```

with no value

```
 $state= '';
         $city= '';
        if(!empty($city) && !empty($state) ){   // if its having no value then still value of session is same 
                $this->session->set_userdata('state',$state);
                 $this->session->set_userdata('cities',$city);
            }
            print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

output is

```
Array ( [session_id] => 2c717eb44e99fb1def09af56250aa5bc [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36 [last_activity] => 1396079813 [user_data] => [id] => 2 [name] => [state] => sadfasd [cities] => fddsfdf )
```

Comment: using this i `var_dump($state.'--'.$city);` first time it's coming like `string 'Bangalore--Arekere'` same on click of pagination link it displaying `string '--'`

Comment: did you check your session expiration time

Comment: because for city and state you used, fixed data like `$state= 'asdasd';
$city= 'asdasd';`